# How to consolidate several transaction tables a query with each table representing a status?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have transaction tables that are related to a main table Order. I would like to consolidate all these transactions into an order history query, such that each transaction and its date is presented as a status of the order at a point in time.

What query would provide the following output?

Order Table

```
Order ID
1
2
```

Order Confirmation Table

```
Order Confirmation ID    Date
1                        2015-08-01
2                        2015-08-01
```

Order Cancellation Table

```
Order Cancellation ID    Date
1                        2015-08-02
```

Order Completion Table

```
Order Completion ID    Date
2                      2015-08-02
```

Output:

```
Order ID    Date          Status
1           2015-08-01    Confirmed
2           2015-08-01    Confirmed
1           2015-08-02    Cancelled
2           2015-08-02    Completed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select o.orderid,
oc.date,
'Cancelled' as status   
from order o
join order_cancellation oc 
on o.orderid = oc.orderid
union
select o.orderid,
ol.date,
'Completed' as status 
from order o
join order_completed ol
on o.orderid = ol.orderid
```

You can use a union query to achieve this.